# Adding multiple condition to CodeIgniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

This my code

```
public function get_news($NewsId = FALSE)
{
    if ($NewsId === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
        $config['per_page'];
        $this->uri->segment(3);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get_where('news',
                             array('NewsId' => $NewsId,
                                    'Language' => '2');
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

this not working if I remove the Language condition so it works

In up code I want to add one more condition like
currently is `NewId => $NewsId` and I want to add one more here in this code `LanId = $LanId`

Answer (score 2):

```
$this-db->where(field1,condition1);
$this-db->where(field2,condition2);
$this-db->where(field3,condition3);
$this->db->get(table);
```

you can set as many as you wish

there's litereally no difference. but since you insist,

```
$this->db->get_where('table',
    array('field1'=>'condition1',
          'field2'=>'condition2',
          'field3'=>'condition3')
);
```

Comment: it's right but on one query, on my current query, will please add one more condition on my current array not change my query just add one more conditioin

Comment: there's no difference. it's a query builder in the end of the day. there's no reason why u can use `get_where` but not `where`

Comment: just i writ my model  if i use $this->db_where then ther will be problem on other place of my project so i don't have to change the layout just add condition

Comment: all you need to to is just loop through your array of conditions and do where clauses for each of them